# Group zipcodes into new categories if it contains value in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Trying to build an aggregate query that would allow me to categorize zipcodes and return the count for each group.

The docuement looks in part like

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("value"), 
"updatedAt" : ISODate("value"), 
"zip" : "11209", 
"state" : "NY", 
"city" : "New York", 
}
```

I would like to group by comparing the "zip" field to an array with n number of mutually exclusive values

```
east_ny_zipcodes = [11209, 11210, 11211, ...]
lower_ny_zipcodes = [11212, 11213, 11214, ...]
```

ideally returning something like

```
{
lower_ny: 1200, 
upper_ny: 1500,
east_ny: 2000
}
```

Comment: You can use `$group` with `$cond` and compare arrays for each category in its own cond. Something like `db.collection_name.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "east_ny": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$in": [
              "$zip",
              "east_ny_zipcodes"
            ]
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})`. You can add `$match` stage with `$or` to limit the zip codes to process in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MongoDB since 3.4 you can use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) to get a comparison to an array:

```
db.zips.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "lower_ny": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$in": [ "$zip", lower_ny_zipcodes ] },1,0]
      }
    },
    "east_ny": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$in": [ "$zip", east_ny_zipcodes ] },1,0]
      }
    },
    "upper_ny": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$in": [ "$zip", upper_ny_zipcodes ] },1,0]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

If you don't have that then there is [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) since MongoDB 2.6. A little different in syntax and intent. But your lists are "unique" so it's not a problem:

```
db.zips.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "lower_ny": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$setIsSubset": [ ["$zip"], lower_ny_zipcodes ] },1,0]
      }
    },
    "east_ny": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$setIsSubset": [ ["$zip"], east_ny_zipcodes ] },1,0]
      }
    },
    "upper_ny": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$setIsSubset": [ ["$zip"], upper_ny_zipcodes ] },1,0]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

In essence it's just a logical comparison to your externally defined array content, which gets expanded in the BSON content sent as the operation.

Of course your values in the array must also be "strings" in order to match. But that's easy done if you have not already:

```
east_ny_zipcodes = [11209, 11210, 11211, ...].map( n => n.toString() );
```

Comment: Is it possible to have it return both the count for each category, but also the list of grouped items like a normal $eq query would. Want to do a spot check to make sure it's right. 

Thanks! I was using the $in operator but didn't use the $cond first. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @MeirSnyder You seem to be asking for [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) which is another accumulator that builds an array from content found in the items matching the grouping boundaries. Note that the 16MB limit still applies, so if you are constructing grouped documents with array content that breaches that you will error. Alternately `$in` just returns a boolean, so you can always `$project` or `$addFields` with the boolean evaluation alongside the existing data without any grouping.